# Show only Unread document current View?

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

anyone have a suggest to realize @Command([ViewShowOnlyUnread]) in XPages ViewPanel?

And is possibile realize the function "Next Unread" and "Previus Unread"?

Comment: For show unread document I use dojo.jquery()
-------------------
dojo.query(".xspDataTable tr").forEach(function(node, index, arr){
if (node.className.indexOf("xspDataTableRowUnread")==-1){
 node.className+=" lotusHidden"
}
console.log(node.className)
});
-------------------

But there are nothing about the Next Unread and Preview Unread function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of binding the view panel to a standard view data source, try setting its value attribute to the following expression:

```
importPackage(com.ibm.xsp.model.domino);
var targetView = database.getView("Some View");
var unreadEntries = targetView.getAllUnreadEntries();
var unreadModel = new DominoViewEntryCollectionDataModel(unreadEntries);
return unreadModel;
```

The view panel should then behave exactly as it would if it were bound to a true data source, but only display the unread entries.

Comment: Uhhh very good point Tim, but...how can I insert your code so that when I click in the button can whitch datasouces?
Tnx you very much

Comment: I have try your code in static Mode but generate this error:
Error while executing JavaScript computed expression
Script interpreter error, line=5, col=8: Cannot find java public constructor 'com.ibm.xsp.model.domino.DominoViewEntryCollectionDataModel()'

Comment: I have changed the last line with  return (unreadModel);
But don't seem work your solution in my view...
The VAR variable don't pass correct class and go in error...
I don't know

Answer (score 1):

Excellent answer from Tim..

Here's other version with Repeat Controls -

```
    <xp:repeat id="repeatUnreadEntries" var="viewEntry" indexVar="index" rows="30">
    <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript: return database.getView('viewName').getAllUnreadEntries()}]]></xp:this.value>
    <xp:this.facets>
        <xp:panel id="repeatHeader" xp:key="header">
            <xp:text disableTheme="true" escape="false">
                <xp:this.value>
                    <![CDATA[<TABLE><THEAD><TH>Cell1</TH><TH>Cell2</TH></THEAD><TBODY>]]>
                </xp:this.value>
            </xp:text>
        </xp:panel>
        <xp:panel id="repeatFooter" xp:key="footer">
            <xp:text disableTheme="true" escape="false">
                <xp:this.value><![CDATA[</TBODY></TABLE>]]></xp:this.value>
            </xp:text>
        </xp:panel>
    </xp:this.facets>
    <TR>
        <xp:repeat var="entryColVal" indexVar="colIndex" value="#{javascript:viewEntry.getColumnValues()}">
            <TD>
                <xp:text value="#{entryColVal}" />
            </TD>
        </xp:repeat>
    </TR>
</xp:repeat>
```

Answer (score 0):

The code provided by Tim Works if you set data and value attributes to view panel, like below.

```
<xp:viewPanel rows="30" id="viewPanel1">
    <xp:this.facets>
        <xp:pager partialRefresh="true" layout="Previous Group Next" xp:key="headerPager" id="pager1"></xp:pager>
    </xp:this.facets>
    <xp:this.data>
        <xp:dominoView var="view1" viewName="vwSrc"></xp:dominoView>
    </xp:this.data>
    <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:importPackage(com.ibm.xsp.model.domino);
var targetView = database.getView("vwSrc");
var unreadEntries = targetView.getAllUnreadEntries();
var unreadModel = new DominoViewEntryCollectionDataModel(unreadEntries);
return unreadModel();}]]></xp:this.value>
        <xp:viewColumn columnName="col1" id="viewColumn1">
            <xp:viewColumnHeader value="Column1" id="viewColumnHeader1"></xp:viewColumnHeader>
        </xp:viewColumn>
</xp:viewPanel>
```

Comment: I don't know why..but in my scenario if I cut and paste the code...I see the vwSrc complete with all entries...
I Use 8.5.3FP2 Server and Designer....

Comment: Did you modified the view name in data attribute and value attribute as well??. Other than that i don't see any issue...

Comment: Yes....the name in data attribute and the value attribute are the same...Have you try the code and in your scenario work well?

Comment: i tried it and it worked well. If you still have problems with this code, you can use repeat control as provided in my answer.

Comment: Tnx you, but I can't use a repeat control, my view have different categorization and is more complex because have indentation with response document etc...
Now I try the test with a simple view. Tnx